# What's the deal with being allowed to define a struct in the return type of a function definition? (C)

Tags: c

Recently I stumbled upon some C code where the return type of a function definition was in itself a struct definition. For example, this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct f {
    int a[25];       
    const char* ch;
} 
function(int h)
{
    printf("Passed: %d\n", h);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("array at: %p ptr : %p\n", function(4).a, function(5).ch);
    int *ptr = function(6).a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
      ptr[i] = i;
      printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);
    }
    puts("No segfaults.");
    return 0;
}
```

You can test this yourself [here](https://repl.it/repls/CompatibleMotherlyAxis).

My question is why would something like this be allowed? What benefits does it actually have over defining a `struct` normally? You can't init the variables, unless, I guess, you create a `struct` inside a function, change its data and then `return` it. Which is pretty standard-fare, but the thing is, under `clang 7.0.0` you don't even need to `return` anything! I thought non `void` functions having no `return` statements was a compiler error (with the only exception being `main`), but `clang` lets you off the hook with a warning.

And also we can be sure that each function call results in an object created, as the code I gave doesn't segfault. *Although I'm not sure why it doesn't as the `struct` is being allocated on the stack and whenever it would go out of scope (which is right when `function` ends) it would get deallocated and the address would become invalid. In my code I can write to a location which my program no longer owns and for some reason it doesn't segfault, but I don't exclude the possibility of it being UB.*

Comment: Your function `function()` doesn't return anything, yet you try to use a value it returns, making this whole thing undefined behavior.

Comment: @Shawn If it doesn't return anything how come the variables have actual addresses? And writing to them doesn't result in a segfault? And how can it not return anything if it's supposed to return a struct, does it simply ignore that?

Comment: @PlatonMakovsky undefined behavior doesn't guarantee a segfault - you can't predict what will happen in this case.

Comment: @Shawn In C, unlike C++, omitting return statement is legal. And most compilers actually honor this difference.

Comment: @StaceyGirl No, it's not. Omitting `return 0;` in `main` will insert a `return 0;`. In functions other than `main` it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Nowhere in the standard it says omitting return is undefined. Instead it explicitly states that "A function may have any number of return statements". This is most likely exists for backward compatibility with older C code that didn't have `void`. You can check it yourself - all major compilers will change generated code when switching to C mode (`-x c`).

Comment: @StaceyGirl You can safely not return a value from a function that's supposed to return something *if* the caller ignores the return value. Not the case here. One of the answers cites the relevant part of the standard.

Comment: @Shawn Oh, yeah, I missed the part about using returned value...

Comment: @user3386109: No, the lifetime of the return value ends far before the return from `main`. Dereferencing `ptr` is UB here even if the function had returned a value.

Comment: @StaceyGirl You're wrong. The standard states that this is undefined behavior: *"The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: [...] --- The `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller (6.9.1).*"

Comment: @S.S.Anne None of compilers think I am wrong though - they all honor function omitting return statement when compiling in C mode, but not in C++ mode. Standard is hard to interpret correctly. It might even be considered a bug in the standard itself (if it means that returned value is used).

Comment: @StaceyGirl Yeah, add `-std=c11 -pedantic` to that and you'll see. It's undefined but that doesn't mean that they can't compile it.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I was talking about code generation. They all explicitly change generated code when switching to C mode. So no, it is not "just compiles". It is part of backward compatibility - before `void` all functions had to return `int`, even when there was nothing to return, so `return` could be omitted.

Comment: @R.. Yes, you are correct (6.2.4/8). Comment withdrawn.

Comment: @StaceyGirl OK, but don't say it's legal. Because it's not according to the standard.

Comment: @S.S.Anne My point was that "returning" _is_ legal according to the standard. Using the value wasn't, but I misread the original comment (missed the middle part). Your quote only confirms this: "...and the value of the function call is used". Using the value is UB anyway, yes.

Comment: @StaceyGirl OK, yeah, if you don't use the value. But you have no knowledge if the function's value is going to be used or not if it's a global function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is why would something like this be allowed?

There are many things allowed in the C grammar that may not be particularly good style.

> under clang 7.0.0 you don't even need to return anything! I thought non void functions having no return statements was a compiler error (with the only exception being main), but clang lets you off the hook with a warning.

It is not an error nor undefined behavior to flow out of a function with non-`void` return type without a `return` as long as the caller does not use the value (6.9.1p12 of the C standard).

But it is ***very*** bad style to do because then callers have to be aware of the conditions where they can or not use the return value (plus the return value is commonly used for error codes in C which the caller needs to check anyway) so all compilers implement a warning.

> unless, I guess, you create a struct inside a function, change its data and then return it.

Well, that is the point: you can declare a `struct` in-place to return several values from a function.

> Although I'm not sure why it doesn't as the struct is being allocated on the stack and whenever it would go out of scope (which is right when function ends) it would get deallocated and the address would become invalid.

You are returning by value, there is nothing wrong with that. If what you say were true, even returning an `int` would be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's syntatically and semantically valid and prohibiting it would increase complexity in the compiler. It makes no sense to prohibit something that the benefits of leaving could exceed the costs of keeping.

Comment: It makes sense to prohibit something that does not need to be prohibited and may be useful if the benefits of prohibiting it (e.g., decrease bugs due to inadvertent occurrence or bad design choices) exceed the costs (loss of opportunity to use a rarely useful feature). Not saying that is the case here, but it is not a correct criterion to choose to leave something simply because it could conceivably be useful.